# Creating a matrix of a certain size from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I am wanting to solve a systems of equations through linalg.solve(A, b) Solve a linear matrix equation, or system of linear scalar equations from scipy.org. Specifically, I have two dictionaries, dict1 and dict1, and I need to convert them to matrices in order to use the above script.

```
 food = ['fruits', 'vegetables', 'bread', 'meat']
 frequency = ['daily', 'rarely']
 consumptions = {'fruits': {'daily': 6, 'rarely': 4}, 'vegetables': {'daily': 8, 'rarely': 6}, 'bread': {'daily': 2, 'rarely': 1}, 'meat': {'daily': 2, 'rarely': 1}}

dict1 = {}
for f in food: #type of food
    for j in food: 
        dict2 = {}
        total = 0.
        for q in frequency:
            dict2.update({q:(consumptions.get(j).get(q)*consumptions.get(f).get(q))}) 
            key = f+'v'+j #comparing the different foods
         dict1.update({key:dict2})
```

This gives me:

```
{'breadvbread': {'daily': 4, 'rarely': 1},
'breadvfruits': {'daily': 12, 'rarely': 4},
'breadvmeat': {'daily': 4, 'rarely': 1},
'breadvvegetables': {'daily': 16, 'rarely': 6},
'fruitsvbread': {'daily': 12, 'rarely': 4},
'fruitsvfruits': {'daily': 36, 'rarely': 16},
'fruitsvmeat': {'daily': 12, 'rarely': 4},
'fruitsvvegetables': {'daily': 48, 'rarely': 24},
'meatvbread': {'daily': 4, 'rarely': 1},
'meatvfruits': {'daily': 12, 'rarely': 4},
'meatvmeat': {'daily': 4, 'rarely': 1},
'meatvvegetables': {'daily': 16, 'rarely': 6},
'vegetablesvbread': {'daily': 16, 'rarely': 6},
'vegetablesvfruits': {'daily': 48, 'rarely': 24},
'vegetablesvmeat': {'daily': 16, 'rarely': 6},
'vegetablesvvegetables': {'daily': 64, 'rarely': 36}}
```

I would like to convert this into a 4 x 4 matrix since I am using 4 types of foods. I did not put dict2 as once I figure out how to convert to a matrix with one dictionary, I can do the other but if you need it, I can update.

I am new to Python and wanted to play around with dictionaries and the matrix solver :) . It was easy to do it with arrays, but now I want to see how to go about if I have dictionaries.

Comment: can you give an example to understand what do you mean by converting it to 4x4 matrix? And what's the system you're trying to solve?

Comment: While doing the permutation & combination, you should consider using "V" or an underscore for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a numpy array from the dictionary using list comprehensions:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[(consumptions[x]["daily"]*consumptions[y]["daily"],
                  consumptions[x]["rarely"]*consumptions[y]["rarely"])
                  for y in food]
                  for x in food])
```

This will give you:

```
array([[[36, 16],
        [48, 24],
        [12,  4],
        [12,  4]],

       [[48, 24],
        [64, 36],
        [16,  6],
        [16,  6]],

       [[12,  4],
        [16,  6],
        [ 4,  1],
        [ 4,  1]],

       [[12,  4],
        [16,  6],
        [ 4,  1],
        [ 4,  1]]])
```

This is a 4x4x2 array:

```
> A.shape
(4, 4, 2)
```

Then, to get a 4x4 matrix of the `daily` values and the `rarely` values separately, use numpy's advanced slicing.
Unlike Python lists, numpy arrays can be sliced over multiple dimensions at once.  This is done by placing a slice object (ex: 3:, 0, :) within the brackets for each dimension of the array, separated by commas.
Our array, `A`, has three dimensions:

```
> A.ndim
3
```

The third dimension indicates whether a value is "daily" (0) or "rarely" (1).  So to get all of the daily values, we want all of the rows (:), all of the columns (:), and only the first entry in the third dimension (0).  With numpy's advanced slicing, we just separte the slice we want for each dimension with commas:

```
> daily = A[:, :, 0]
> daily

array([[36, 48, 12, 12],
       [48, 64, 16, 16],
       [12, 16,  4,  4],
       [12, 16,  4,  4]])


> rarely = A[:, :, 1]
> rarely

array([[16, 24,  4,  4],
       [24, 36,  6,  6],
       [ 4,  6,  1,  1],
       [ 4,  6,  1,  1]])
```

If you want to make the meaning of these values more explicit, you can convert the numpy arrays to a pandas DataFrame:

```
> import pandas as pd

> df = pd.DataFrame(daily, columns=food, index=food)
> df

            fruits  vegetables  bread   meat
fruits      36      48          12      12
vegetables  48      64          16      16
bread       12      16          4       4
meat        12      16          4       4
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing for more info on advanced slicing.

Comment: Thank you kindly. This is exactly what I was looking for. I feel that as a beginner, I am still learning the basics before I can move on to pandas. Thank you for the panda example though! I am looking forward to learning pandas soon.

Comment: Can you please explain the advance slicing? I am having trouble understanding how that is creating a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: I updated my answer to go into more details about advanced slicing.